# Unable to find reference to assembly in a Visual Studio website

Tags: asp.net, reference

I have a legacy WebSite project (as opposed to a Web Application project).  It was using .net 3.5 but I am updating it to 4.0.

Due to the compilation error ...

```
 Compiler Error Message: CS1705: Assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'System.Web.WebPages, 
    Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has 
    a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, 
    Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

... I added a reference to the newer version of System.Web.WebPages.  This added the following line to the web.config file:

```
 <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

However, when I try to build the website I get this error:

```
 The type 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage' exists in both 
    c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.dll' 
    and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.dll'
```

I cannot seem to find a reference anywhere in the project to the v4.0 1 version of WebPages.  I assume this means that some other assembly is probably referring to it but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any idea how to track down what is referring to the assembly and either remove the reference or update the calling the assembly?

Comment: Did you try the fix mentioned at http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253815?

Comment: I hadn't see it before but am looking now.  Not sure it will help because the section I believe you are referring me to is for a Web Application (it has a project file). This WebSite is not a project and thus does not have a project file to edit.  But perhaps there is something else in there that will help...